# react-intersection-observer always returns true in the beginning if I refresh the page

Tags: css, reactjs

My landing page has 3 sections

I put `ref={ref}` in my second page then I refresh the page

**Expected:**

I expect `inView`  to return false only in the beginning, and then becomes true when I scroll down.

**Actual**
return `false`->`false`->`true`->`false`

[image]

[image]

I guess the reason for this is like this :
landing page before load ====>       `inView = false`

landing page before is loading  ====> `inView = false`

landing page fully loaded, the observer "sees" page 2 ===>  `inView = true`

page 2 is quickly pushed to the bottom as I am supposed to see page 1 on first load ===>  `inView = false`

but I have no idea how to solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out

need to wrap the content in the first page and then set view height = 100 vh in css

e.g.

```
<div className="firstPage"> <-set this 100vh
   ddd
</div>
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, but I have multiple InView wrappers in my page, and they are all loading right away.... OH, I think I understand the issue.. if they are all at 0 height, they will all fit.. and thus they are "visible"? oh.. just dawned on me.... lol